# Error Raised in VBA not propagating to powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a powershell script that runs an MS Access macro:

```
$MsAccessDb= New-Object -ComObject Access.Application -ErrorAction Stop
```

then in a foreach statement does this:

```
  ...
 $MsAccessDb.OpenCurrentDatabase($file)
  $MsAccessDb.DoCmd.RunMacro('mcrUpdate')
  ...
```

This macro calls a VBA function that refreshes an excel report. Now, errors are handled in the vba function using Err.Raise.I intentionally force an error to occur in the VBA and the error is thrown (in a dialog box). But when i run the macro using powershell it does not catch the error eventhough i am using -ErrorAction to trap non-terminating errors.

What i am doing wrong. I need to propagate this errors from MS Access application to powershell so that an email alert will capture it.

The url is the redacted error image raised from VBA when i run the VBA script alone. For some reasons i cannot explain this error is not propagated to powershell when i run the MS Access macro from powershell:
[image: click to view redacted image]

Comment: `-ErrorAction Stop` here is only used for the purpose of creating the object. It is not propagated to every method/function of that object. you need to capture those error on a case by case basis. Is this a terminating error? `try{$MsAccessDb.DoCmd.RunMacro('mcrUpdate')}catch{write-host "something happened"}`. What does PowerShell do when it fails?

Comment: If there is more to that comment please add those details to the question.

Comment: _you need to capture those error on a case by case basis_ just wanted to amend that statement. You can set global error actions but you steal need to deal with the errors themselves on a case by case.

Comment: Actually the portion where i run the macro is done in a try/catch block.  so basically i do this foreach($file in $files){ try {  ...
 $MsAccessDb.OpenCurrentDatabase($file)
  $MsAccessDb.DoCmd.RunMacro('mcrUpdate')
  ...} catch { throw $Error[0].Exception ...}}The catch block so far traps terminating errors and i get emails on them. However, some errors that are thrown by the VBA are not propagated. I presumed those are non-terminating errors, so included the -ErrorAction in the definition of the Access.Application object in powershell.

Comment: If the errors are non terminating then you need to capture and examine output from the command (if any). You could also change the global `$ErrorActionPreference` before execution of the macro to Stop and then set it back to Continue after (or record its state before you change it. ). That should make it trigger a `try` theoretically.

Comment: @Matt have tried your suggestions, but still not getting the desired results. I have edited the original question to include the redacted error from VBA when i run the VBA script alone. pls bear in mind i am artificially creating this error. The error is thrown by VBA but for some reasons its not captured when i run the same macro with powershell.

Comment: So PowerShell does not see anything when the macro fails? It looks like you need to handle that error in the macro first